# Bad state: GetIt: Object/factory with type <> is not registered inside GetIt

Tags: dart, testing, dependency-injection, get-it

I am trying to use dependency injection with `get_it` package, in order to make unit tests.

I am using these dependencies :

```yaml
get_it: ^7.6.0
injectable_generator: ^2.1.6
```

My `main` function looks like this :

```dart
void main(List<String> args) async {
  // Configure injection
  await setup(Env.test);
  await getIt.allReady();

  // [...]
}
```

I wait for the setup with the `test` environment, and I wait for it to be `allReady`.

The file uses `injection.dart`, which contains the `setup()` function :

```dart
GetIt getIt = GetIt.instance;

@InjectableInit(preferRelativeImports: false)
setup(String env) {
  getIt.init();
  if (env == Env.test) {
    getIt.registerLazySingleton<IAuthRepository>(() => TestAuthRepository());
  } else {
    getIt.registerLazySingleton<IAuthRepository>(() => AuthRepository());
  }
}

abstract class Env {
  // static const dev = 'dev';
  static const prod = 'prod';
  static const test = 'test';
}
```

As you can see, I want to use `AuthRepository` for production (will call a database), or `TestAuthRepository` for unit tests (will not call the database).

I declared theses class here, in a file `auth_repository.dart` :

```dart
abstract class IAuthRepository {
  Future<int> createNewUser({
    required String login,
    required String email,
    required String password,
  });
}

@Injectable(as: IAuthRepository, env: [Env.prod])
class AuthRepository extends BaseRepository implements IAuthRepository {

  @override
  Future<int> createNewUser({
    required String login,
    required String email,
    required String password,
  }) async {
    try {
      final connection = await getDatabaseConnection();

      // ... (make the database call) ...

      return 1;
    } catch (exception) {
      print(exception);
      return -1;
    }
  }
}

@Injectable(as: IAuthRepository, env: [Env.test])
class TestAuthRepository extends BaseRepository implements IAuthRepository {

  @override
  Future<int> createNewUser({required String login, required String email, required String password}) {
    return Future.value(2);
  }
}
```

For now, the testing function `createNewUser` will only return 2.

I am launching my test here :

```dart
void main() {

  AuthController authController = AuthController();

  test('Registration success', () async {

    int response = await authController.register(
      login: 'test',
      email: 'email@mail.com',
      password: 'Testing193!',
      passwordConfirmation: 'Testing193!',
    );
    expect(response, 1);
  });
  
  // ...
}
```

This test calls for `authController.register()`, which is here :

```dart
  Future<int> register({
    required String login,
    required String email,
    required String password,
    required String passwordConfirmation,
  }) async {

    // [...]

    // IAuthRepository authRepository = getIt<IAuthRepository>();
    IAuthRepository authRepository = getIt.get<IAuthRepository>();
    return await authRepository.createNewUser(
      login: login,
      email: email,
      password: password,
    );
  }
```

I try to retrieve an `IAuthRepository` instance with `getIt`.

However, when I am launching my tests, I get this error :

```
00:00 +0 -1: Registration success [E]                                                                                                                     
  Bad state: GetIt: Object/factory with type IAuthRepository is not registered inside GetIt. 
  (Did you accidentally do GetIt sl=GetIt.instance(); instead of GetIt sl=GetIt.instance;
  Did you forget to register it?)
  package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart 12:19                 throwIfNot
  package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart 395:5                 _GetItImplementation._findFactoryByNameAndType
  package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart 423:29                _GetItImplementation.get
  package:toast/controllers/auth_controller.dart 31:44  AuthController.register
  test/controllers/auth_controller_test.dart 23:41      main.<fn>
```

I thought I registered my `IAuthRepository` class, however it does not work. How can I register it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally made it work.

Here was the problem : The `setup()` function, which registered all the class implementations I needed, was called in the `main()` function (yes, that IS silly from me...).

However, as unit tests are launched specifically to each class, the `main()` function was never invoked.

So, my test now looks like this :

```dart
void main() {

  setUpAll(() {
    setupGetIt(Env.test);
  });

  tearDownAll(() {
    unregisterGetIt();
  });

  AuthController authController = AuthController();

  test('Registration success', () async {
    int response = await authController.register(
      login: 'test',
      email: 'email@mail.com',
      password: 'Testing193!',
      passwordConfirmation: 'Testing193!',
    );
    expect(response, 1);
  });
}
```

The `setupGetIt()` function is the same as `setup()` (I renamed it to be more clear), it takes care of registering every class I need.

I call it in a `setUpAll()` function, in order to register it before all the tests.
Note that I also added a `unregisterGetIt()` function, which basically only calls `getIt.reset()` to unregister every registered class. It is called in `tearDownAll()`, which is called after all tests.

I also removed all the `@Injectable()` annotation on top of my implemented class, as they are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Well we need a change in Service Locator:

First we need to register service/repo and then register store/provider with it as given below.

```
final getIt = GetIt.instance;

Future<void> setUpLocator() async {
// Register Repositories:
getIt.registerSingleton<SwitchRepo>(SwitchRepo());

// Register Stores with Repositories:
getIt.registerSingleton<SwitchStore>(SwitchStore(getIt<SwitchRepo>()));
}
```